# QuickBooks POS certificate - How to know if the user selects "No"

Tags: quickbooks

When a user installs my app one of the first questions is the "Trust Certificate" question.  The user can select "Yes, this time", "Yes, always" or "No"  Regardless of the option clicked the code continues on its merry way ... 
Can anyone give me a pointer as to how I would catch the users response and act accordingly in my code.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer for anyone who may need to know:

Using a Try/Catch within the VB.NET script does not return an error when the user disallows access.  However using an OnError will catch an error of "Access Denied".